# How parse this type of Json swift using swifty variable , iwant the Unit number to an array and get the details from the tag

Tags: ios, swift

```
{
"responseMessage": "GetVisitorDetailsForSecurity Details",
"responseData": "{\"UnitVisitor\":{\"VisitorID\":23123124,\"CommunityID\":234,\"UnitNo\":\"73234901\",\"VisitorMobileNo\":9723243477,\"VisitorName\":\"N224423tor 1\",\"ImageUrl\":\"http:\/\/64.202.188.25\/SLFAPI\/Images\/img-24324342357-16-PM.jpeg\",\"VisitorTypeID\":1,\"VisitorT4ype\":\"hjjdjf\",\"ddfd\":\"EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT\",\"VisitorEntryStatus\":\",EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT,EXIT\",\"EveryVisitor\":\"False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False\",\"CreatedBy\":457,\"CreatedByMobileNo\":s34343,\"CreatedDate\":\"2019-11ewq-13T17:55:09\",\"UpdatedBy\":0,\"UpdatedDate\":\"0001-0werewr1-01T00:00:00\",\"Status\":\"ACTIVE\"}}",
"responseCode": "00"
}
```

Comment: The nested JSON isn't actually valid JSON. The value to `CreatedByMobileNo` is not valid.

Comment: ```CreatedByMobileNo``` is nither a number nor a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `responseData` is `JSON` value whose type is `String` so first convert it into `JSON`.
Your code will look like this

```
if(response.result.isSuccess) { 
    let swiftyJsonVar = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
    print(swiftyJsonVar!) 
    let resultarray = swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"].stringValue

    //This line of code covert String into JSON.
    let responseDataValue = JSON(parseJSON: resultarray)
    print(responseDataValue) 

    print(responseDataValue["UnitVisitor"]["UnitNo"].stringValue)
}
```

In the above code what I am doing is converting value of `responseData` in `JSON` format. After converting into `JSON` you can access any value.

Comment: and how can i acces the unit vistor and all other tags

Comment: just like you accessing the dictionary values https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-parse-json-using-swiftyjson, for more details go through this link

Comment: i jutst go throught it but i cant understand will u explain

Comment: I just updated my answer, hope you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Please note responseData is a string and an object.

This is how it's done using codable, the simplest way.

```
struct DataModel: Codable {
let responseMessage, responseData, responseCode: String?
```

}

If you aren't aware of Codables check this [link](https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1).

For more, please clarify your question.

Comment: if(response.result.isSuccess)
            {
                let swiftyJsonVar = try? JSON(data: response.data!)
                
                 print(swiftyJsonVar!)
                
               
                let resultarray = swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"]
                
                
                print(resultarray)
                
                
                
                
                
        
                
            
            
                
            
             
            }
        }

Comment: this is how i do right now

Comment: i want to get this unit vistor part to an array

Comment: @nidhinshiju Please add your parsing code in the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

if(response.result.isSuccess) { let swiftyJsonVar = try? JSON(data: response.data!) print(swiftyJsonVar!) let resultarray = swiftyJsonVar!["responseData"] print(resultarray) } }

Comment: this is my parsing code

Comment: Edit your question with that code, that's not an answer. And format it.